# Android: приложение во весь экран на планшете

Tags: android, экран

У корневого layout в атрибуте background у меня стоит следующий xml файл:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:src="@drawable/bckgr1"
android:gravity="bottom|left"
android:tileMode="disabled"/>
```

у картинки в папке drawable-xxhdpi в атрибуте src разрешение 1920*1280 (хотя я пытался и увеличивать её размер, и перемещал её в папку drawable-xxxhdpi), на планшете занимает где-то четверть экрана, что мне делать?

Comment: Автоматически не скейлится потому что ты юзаешь битмап(Битмап это попиксельная картинка, ofc она выводится в своем оригинальном размере, если не делать с ней ни каких манипуляций). Либо воспользуйся другим ресурсов(например дравейбл) либо погугли как скейлить битмап. Не думаю что это составит труда.

Comment: что мешает просто поставить ресурс на фон, без обертки его в bitmap?

Answer (score 2):

Замените `android:gravity="bottom|left"` на `android:gravity="fill"`. Смотрите [документацию](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#bitmap-element).

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте вот так:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:src="@drawable/bckgr1"
android:tileMode="repeat"/>
```

заполнит бэкграунд повторяющимся рисунком